# Does gas price go up when I send a lot of Ethers?

Tags: go-ethereum

If I send a lot of Ether to a different wallet, does it mean that I also have to pay higher gas price because if I remember correctly, gas price varies based on the complexity of the operarion but would the content would affect the prices as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gas used is based on the operations you make. One normal account to account (non contracts) transfer use 21000 gas regardless of amount.

Gas price is how much you are willing to pay per gas used, and this is totally flexible from your end. Pay too little and it won't be included, pay more to be included in the coming few block (even though right now there is no backlog).

So one "normal" transaction between two accounts spend 21000 gas. If you are willing to pay 4GWei per gas, the total price will be (21000 gas * 4Gwei).

Comment: How about Ether transfer from contract to account?

Comment: Then there is no fixed gas usage, it depends on the contract behavior. If it only does a simple send, the gas usage should be reasonable close to 30000 (give or take) gas